How can I fix gap where patio separated from interior wall?
I found this gap between patio door frame and wall/floor in our newly purchased home. How can I repair this gap?


Show us more than this closeup. The problem isn't with the gap--that's just a symptom. It's with the door mounting. Show the exterior, please.
